# Show Category table with parent categories

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below is my table structure:

**Menu Table**

```
id   title  position
--------------------    
1    Test    home
2    Test2   home
```

**Category**

```
cid   name   parent  parent_menu
--------------------------------
 1    ABC      0         1
 2    DEF      0         2
 3    GHI      1         0
 4    JKL      2         0
```

**Category Description**

```
id    cat_id    catdesc   slug
-------------------------------
 1      1       ABC_DESC   abc
 2      2       DEF_DESC   def
 3      3       GHI_DESC   ghi
 4      4       JKL_DESC   jkl
```

- `Menu table` handles the menu title an position.
- `Category table` handles category name and other parameters. (if parent=0 then it means that this is main category and so on..)
- `Category Description table` handles the description, slug and other parameters.

Now i want to display data like as below

```
 Name      Description      Edit         Delete        /*table headings*/
-------------------------------------------------------
  Menu Title: (Test)    Main Category Name: (ABC)      
 ------------------------------------------------------
 GHI       GHI_DESC      edit_icon       delete_icon
 ______________________________________________________
  Menu Title: (Test2)    Main Category Name: (DEF)
 ------------------------------------------------------
  JKL       JKL_DESC      edit_icon       delete_icon
```

I tried to use JOINS and manipulate data in PHP but no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM `category` t1 LEFT JOIN `category_description` t2 ON t1.cid = t2.cat_id WHERE 1
```

Then in PHP i tried like as below

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach($subcat as $sub) { ?>
     <?php if($sub->parent == 0) { ?>
       <tr><td><?php echo $sub->name ?></td></tr>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($sub->parent != 0) { ?>
       <tr><td><?php echo $sub->name ?></td><td><?php echo $sub->catdesc ?></td>
       <td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
     <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And above prints table like as below:

```
Main Category Name: ABC
Main Category Name: DEF
------
GHI  GHI_DESC
JKl  JKL_DESC
```

Please suggest how to print as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming parent_menu is from id in menu table, try this:

```
SELECT t1.title, t2.name, t2.parent, t2.parent_menu, t3.catdesc
FROM menu t1
LEFT JOIN category t2 ON t1.id=t2.parent_menu
LEFT JOIN description t3 ON t2.cid=t3.cat_id
GROUP BY t2.name
```

[sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/281b60/9) and [php demo](https://eval.in/554838)

Comment: Your query does not return GHI and JKL name and description about them.. I said that only description for GHI and JKL shall be reurned

Comment: i tweaked your query and now i get wanted thing :) .. Thanks

Comment: This is creating issues when you have same t2.names :(

Comment: I have update my answer with demo. The problem in the join is due to the zero (0) data in the parent_menu field.

Comment: That is fine but data is not displayed as i mentioned. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use old MySQL method as:

```
select mt.title, cat.name, cdesc.catdesc from menu_title mt, category cat, category_description cdesc where mt.id = cat.parent_menu and cat.cid = cdesc.cat_id
```

Comment: but this is what i am doing.. You have selected particular columns

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you to build a tree and than iterate over the tree with help of the ArrayIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator.
To build your tree you can adjust this code sample:

```
$tree = array();
foreach($result_set as $result) {
    if ($result["parent"] == 0) {
        $tree["cat"][$result["cid"]]["parent"] = $result;
    } else {
        $tree["cat"][$result["parent"]]["child"][$result["cid"] = $result;
    }
}
```

Remember: You have to adjust it!
Then you can implement the iterator like so:

```
class CategorieTreeIterator extends ArrayIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function getChildren()
    {
        $link_data = $this->current();
        $cid       = key($link_data["cat"]);
        return new CategorieTreeIterator($link_data["cat"][$cid]["child"]);
    }

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        $link_data = $this->current();
        $cid       = key($link_data["cat"]);
        return !empty($link_data["cat"][$cid]["child"]);
    }
}
```

Again, you have to adjust it.
To display the data, you can now iterate over use this:

```
$cat_tree_iter = new CategorieTreeIterator($tree);
$rec_iter_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($cat_tree_iter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($rec_iter_iter as $iter) {
    //display data with help of $iter->getDepth();

}
```

Comment: This is complex to deal in my situation ;)

Comment: I know it looks complex, but it really isn't. :-) You just have to create one class and the tree, which shouldn't be too hard with the hints from the above code... Also, if you will add subcategories in the future it will be easy to implement. But if it works with the SQL that will be fine for now too. :)

Comment: yes.. And if i am not wrong then it shall be included as Helper class in MVC ??

Comment: Yes so you can reuse it easily

Comment: But my question is that shall it be new class or i should extend existing helper class (bad idea ;)

Comment: I would prefer a new helper class beacuse you need the CategorieTreeIterator class

Comment: Where do i have to use your first and 3rd block of code.. i have created an Helper class of CategorieTreeIterator

Comment: The 1st block would be in the model/controller. This is important to get an actual tree. You should check it, if it really looks like a tree, and eventually adjust it. The 3rd block would live in the view. Inside the foreach you can create the tables/rows.

Comment: but can i create objects in view?? so, 3rd block (Object thing)shall not be in controller??  and what is model/controller?? as i know model and controller are diff things

Comment: You can create objects in a view. (Depending on the Framework/Template language) If you don't like it, create it in your controller and pass it into the view. I personally can live with this, as far as the object is JUST for the view and does nothing else. The first block can live either in the controller or in the model. This is personal taste I think. If you create a method in the model called getResultAsTree() than you can use it everywhere, or if you don't need it anywhere else, create the tree in the controller. :-)

Comment: yup.. perfectly said now :D :) ;)

Comment: If you like the answer, you can considering it, to give it an upvote ;-)

Comment: I shall try this and surely vote up..  I never stop appreciating right things :)